# How are async tests executed in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to perform testing using Jest. I would like to understand the behaviour of JEST in the following scenarios:

1. **When an async function passed to the test**
2. **When a synchronous function containing an async code passed to a test.**

Please check the below sippet for reference.

I would like to know whether the tests execute asynchronously in both the scenarios.

```
it('should do async stuff...', async () => {
    const result = await doSomething();
    expect(result).toBe('value');
})

it('should do async stuff...', () => {
    async () => {
        const result = await doSomething();
        expect(result).toBe('value');

    }();
})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function of the second test is not declared as `async`, it will run **synchronously**. The self-calling function will be executed but Jest will close the execution scope before anything can happen.

You can clearly see it by yourself with the following code which extends your snippet:

```js
async function doSomething(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("value");
    }, ms)
  );
}

describe("compare async tests", () => {
  it("test 1", async () => {
    const result = await doSomething(2000);
    console.log("test 1", { result });
    expect(result).toBe("value");
  });

  it("test 2", () => {
    (async () => {
      const result = await doSomething(1000);
      console.log("test 2", { result });
      expect(result).toBe("value");
    })();
  });
});
```

Running the above will mark both test as successful but you'll only see "test 1" in the console output.